how do I launch a VS Code extension during automated test, without a command?
how do I launch a VS Code extension during automated test, without a command?
framework: @vscode/test-electron
as a user it is launched by clicking the icon in the VS Code Extensions sidebar
I could not find the vscode API for this kind of action.
